# Custom ORDER BY in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql

Is there a way to do custom order by instead of `ASC` or `DESC`?

There is a picklist field -> `Color__c`  on a custom object - `Products__c` -  which has following values:

1. RED
2. YELLOW
3. BROWN

If i write a SOQL: `Select id, LastOrderDate__c,Color__c from Products__c where Name = 'Shoes' ORDER BY Color__c DESC`

its returning YELLOW,RED,BROWN records in this order

but i want a custom order by which i prioritize RED over YELLOW, is there way do a custom order by instead of `ASC` or `DESC`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do that in SOQL.

You can, if you wish, create a new formula field on your object that maps colors to their desired ordering keys, using something like a `CASE()` formula. You can then order by that formula field.

Note of course that that may come with performance implications, and you'll have to be aware of the formula character limit depending on how many values you have.